# Big Query data totals are wrong, suspect duplicate rows after LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join two tables in Google Big Query and I think it's duplicating a few rows (I'm guessing this because the totals are wrong when I then use the data in Data Studio).

To give some context, I've done something that probably isn't the ideal setup but which seemed easiest for my level of knowledge. I first combined data from a bunch of different sources in Google Sheets before uploading to Big query, all of it is segmented by date but some sources are also segmented by device (they'll be getting filtered into different reports so this isn't a problem for me, although it might be relevant to the issue). All sources have the same columns though, just that some columns will be empty for certain sources (i.e. some not having device).

I then separately upload a set of data that I need to join with the data from a Google sheet based on the campaign name. While this works perfectly for the source that is segmented by device, the totals are all wrong (always too high) for the two sources that aren't segmented by device.

```
SELECT master.*, additional.conversions, additional.campaign_c, additional.Date
FROM `project.dataset.Master` AS master
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.Additional` AS additional
ON master.Campaign = additional.campaign_c AND master.Date = additional.Date AND master.Device = "Mobile" 
OR master.Campaign = additional.campaign_c AND master.Date = additional.Date AND master.Device IS NULL
```

I'm pretty sure the mistake has something to do with the last two lines, but nothing I try seems to fix it.

Edit: sample tables for clarity:

Master

```
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
1 | Date       | Platform   | Campaign   | Device  | Metric 1 | Metric 2 |
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
2 | 2019-10-19 | Platform 1 | Campaign 1 | Mobile  | 1        | 2        |
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
3 | 2019-10-19 | Platform 1 | Campaign 1 | Desktop | 3        | 4        |
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
4 | 2019-10-19 | Platform 1 | Campaign 2 | Tablet  | 56       | 7        |
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
5 | 2019-10-19 | Platform 1 | Campaign 3 | Mobile  | 7        | 9        |
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
6 | 2019-10-19 | Platform 2 | Campaign 4 | null    | 9        | 4        |
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
7 | 2019-10-19 | Platform 2 | Campaign 5 | null    | 3        | 8        |
  +------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Additional

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| Date       | Campaign_c | Metric 3 |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2019-10-19 | Campaign 1 | 2        |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2019-10-19 | Campaign 1 | 4        |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2019-10-19 | Campaign 2 | 7        |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2019-10-19 | Campaign 3 | 9        |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2019-10-19 | Campaign 4 | 4        |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2019-10-19 | Campaign 5 | 8        |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

In this scenario I'd ideally want to add Metric 3 to rows 2, 5, 6, and 7 but leave the other rows alone.

Comment: Can you try putting master.Device = "Mobile" and master.Device IS NULL outside of the on clause?
So essentially - 
SELECT master.*, additional.conversions, additional.campaign_c, additional.Date
FROM `project.dataset.Master` AS master
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.Additional` AS additional
ON master.Campaign = additional.campaign_c AND master.Date = additional.Date WHERE master.Device = "Mobile" 
 OR master.Device IS NULL

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query has no "total"s, so the question is rather hard to follow.

Comment: @user3115056 The problem with that is that I'd then be filtering out all the data where device is desktop, for example, even if I still want to keep that data regardless of it not having a match with the additional data.

Comment: @Jul - can you show expected result? what would be metric 3 for  row 2 as I see two matches for it in additional table? should it be combined as 2,4 or should it end up with two rows instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT r.*, Metric_3 FROM (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(m) r, ARRAY_AGG(Metric_3) AS Metric_3
  FROM `project.dataset.master` m
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.additional` a
  USING (Campaign, `Date`)
  WHERE IFNULL(Device, 'Mobile') = 'Mobile' 
  GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', m)
)
```

if to apply to sample data in  your question - result is

```
Row date        Platform    Campaign    Device  Metric_1    Metric_2    Metric_3     
1   2019-10-19  Platform 1  Campaign 1  Mobile  1           2           2    
                                                                        4    
2   2019-10-19  Platform 1  Campaign 3  Mobile  7           9           9    
3   2019-10-19  Platform 2  Campaign 4  null    9           4           4    
4   2019-10-19  Platform 2  Campaign 5  null    3           8           8
```

> I'd still like the other rows to be kept in the data (rows 3 and 4), i jsut don't want them to get any of the additional data added to them

Use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT r.*, IF(IFNULL(r.Device, 'Mobile') = 'Mobile', Metric_3, []) AS Metric_3 
FROM (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(m) r, ARRAY_AGG(Metric_3) AS Metric_3
  FROM `project.dataset.master` m
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.additional` a
  USING (Campaign, `Date`)
  GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', m)
)
```

this produces

```
Row date        Platform    Campaign    Device  Metric_1    Metric_2    Metric_3     
1   2019-10-19  Platform 1  Campaign 1  Mobile  1           2           2    
                                                                        4    
2   2019-10-19  Platform 1  Campaign 1  Desktop 3           4        
3   2019-10-19  Platform 1  Campaign 2  Tablet  56          7        
4   2019-10-19  Platform 1  Campaign 3  Mobile  7           9           9    
5   2019-10-19  Platform 2  Campaign 4  null    9           4           4    
6   2019-10-19  Platform 2  Campaign 5  null    3           8           8
```

> getting an error because 'Campaign in USING clause not found on right side of table' - pretty sure this is because the right table has 'campaign_c' instead of 'campaign'

If join columns names are different  - use ON instead of USING as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT r.*, IF(IFNULL(r.Device, 'Mobile') = 'Mobile', Metric_3, []) AS Metric_3 
FROM (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(m) r, ARRAY_AGG(Metric_3) AS Metric_3
  FROM `project.dataset.master` m
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.additional` a
  ON m.Campaign = a.campaign_c AND m.Date = a.Date
  GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', m)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I'd still like the other rows to be kept in the data (rows 3 and 4), i jsut don't want them to get any of the additional data added to them. Is this even possible?

Comment: Thanks! Pretty sure this is it, just getting an error because 'Campaign in USING clause not found on right side of table' - pretty sure this is because the right table has 'campaign_c' instead of 'campaign', is there a way to tell it where to look? had a google but honestly i'm way out of my depth with this sql you've shared!

Comment: in tables example in your question both tables have Campaign columns. If this is not a case you need to use ON instead of USING. will update my answer in few min

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I mentioned it in the original but not the edit - my bad!

Comment: thanks but this is achieving the same as what I've already tried, it still doesn't seem to be adding up correctly as the total on independent metrics for the new data is different to the master data

Comment: @Jul - based on sample data in your question - can you please show what the expected result? and how it is different from that in my answer. (rather than it can be flatten as in your question - but in this case - what the issue then?) otherwise - looks like you just wasted our time o(

Comment: The expected result is the same one you said it should produce, except when I use your SQL the total cost for each platform increases - which surely shouldn't be the case when all we're adding is a third metric that has nothing to do with cost. Appreciate it's taken ages so sorry about this, think I'm probably just setting the whole thing up wrong from the start so will look into other options

Comment: Finally found the issue - there were duplicates in the additional data which were messing everything up when joining. Will mark your answer as correct, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `Device` has to do with the `JOIN`.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT m.*, a.conversions, a.campaign_c, a.Date
FROM `project.dataset.Master` m LEFT JOIN 
     `project.dataset.Additional` am
     ON m.Campaign = a.campaign_c AND
        m.Date = a.Date ;
```

EDIT:

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT m.*, a.metric_3
FROM `project.dataset.Master` m LEFT JOIN 
     `project.dataset.Additional` am
     ON m.Campaign = a.campaign_c AND
        m.Date = a.Date AND
        (m.Device IS NULL OR m.device = 'Mobile')
```

Comment: The problem is that since the master table is also segmented by device the additional data seems to duplicate itself if I do what you recommended (which is what I originally tried). I've added sample tables now which will hopefully clarify what's going on!

Comment: Thanks but neither of these seem to work, i'm still getting different totals when adding up the totals for a metric that's only in the master data directly on the master data or when adding it up on the combined view, which it shouldn't be doing